# Multilevel Spring Security

Tags: spring, security

I have multiple servlets in my web application. I would like to implement some kind of multilevel security mechanism using Spring Security. What I have:

1. /portal/* -> this level will be accessed by ROLE_ADMIN (configured in XML and password saved in the properties file).
2. /portal/Edrive/* - this level will be accessed by authenticated users from database.

Rest servlets under /portal/ are accessible as ROLE_ADMIN (see p.1). In different words, all levels are under ROLE_STAFF, only Edrive is for ROLE_USER (or smth. like this).

What I am getting now:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A universal match pattern ('/**') is defined  before other patterns in the filter chain, causing them to be ignored. Please check the ordering in your <security:http> namespace or FilterChainProxy bean configuration
```

Here is my applicationContext-security.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<security:http auto-config="true" pattern="/portal/*">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/portal" authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:password-encoder hash="md5"/>
        <security:user-service id="userDetailsService" properties="classpath:users.properties"/>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

edrive-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="edrive"/>
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<security:http auto-config="true" pattern="/portal/Edrive/*">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/myCarLogin" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/myCar*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/myCarLogin" default-target-url="/myCarServices" authentication-failure-url="/myCarloginfailed" />
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/myCarlogout" />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:password-encoder hash="md5"/>
        <security:jdbc-user-service 
                data-source-ref="edriveDataSource"
                users-by-username-query="select name from account where name=? and password=?"/> 
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your applicationContext-security.xml following line is causing an error

```
 <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
```

change it to

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/portal*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
```

then it will work fine.

Regards Shrikant.